# Blink LED without delay

Tags: arduino-uno

So I'm creating a code so that I can read and store temperature values
for at least 8hours and store it in the Arduino EEPROM. I also want the Built in LED to flash once every second, while the temperature sensor records once every minute. I wrote the following but I'm left with the LED staying on for a whole minute then off for another minute and so on. I want it to keep constantly flashing. I know it's because of my delay(6000) but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    #include <EEPROM.h> //Librería para controlar la EEPROM de la Arduino
    float tempC; //Initialize variable for storing Temperature
    int tempPin = 0; //Conected at A0
    int addr = 0; //Cantidad de espacios (bytes) iniciales
    int count = 0; //counter needed to stop at a certain point before overflowing the EEPROM memory
    int Voltages[501]; // Array with space for 501 data Points.A little over 8 hours. Holding integer values of Voltages.
    float Temps[501]; //Holds float values for Temperatures
    const int SWITCH = 8; //set switch to port 8
    int ledState = LOW; // ledState used to set the LED
    unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
    const long interval = 1000;           // blink once per second

  void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(SWITCH,INPUT_PULLUP);}

  void loop(){
  int i;
  if (digitalRead(SWITCH)==HIGH & count<=501){

  for (int i=0;i<EEPROM.length();i++){
    EEPROM.write(i,0);} // Clears the EEPROM so that only new recorded values are shown. In case of terminating before 8h

  Serial.println("-------Recording-------");
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); // current time
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis; // save the last time the LED blinked
      if (ledState == LOW) {// if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
        ledState = HIGH;} else {
        ledState = LOW;}
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledState);}

  for (i=0; i<501; i++){

    count = count+1;
    int v = analogRead(tempPin); // reads voltage 
    Voltages[i] = v; 
    Serial.println(i);
    Serial.println(Voltages[i]); 
    delay(60000); 
    EEPROM.put(addr, Voltages[i]); //stores voltages in EEPROM
    addr= addr +2;}}
```

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution you are looking for involves the use of timer interrupts. That would execute an interrupt service routine (might as well be a blinking led) regardless of what happens in the rest of your loop function. This might give you a better in-sight: [Arduino timer interrupts](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-timer-interrupts)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up changing the interval to 6000 and the delay to 500 off and 500 on and it worked!